# How to use lookup when both the tables have the same key names?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections and both of them have the same key names `platform`, `channel` and `month`. When I am using lookup, the `let` step is taking the variables from the first collection and not the collection `b`. Using the dot operator also does not work.

Another problem is that `month` and `year` operators are not working in `let`.

How do I fix these?

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "b",
        let: { 
          rev_platform: "$b.platform", 
          rev_channel: "$b.channel", 
          rev_month: {$month:'$b.month'}, 
          rev_year: {$year:'$b.month'}
        },
        pipeline: [
            { $match:
            { $expr:
                { $and:
                    [
                    { $eq: [ "$platform",  "$$rev_platform" ] },
                    { $eq: [ "$channel", "$$rev_channel" ] },
                    { $eq: [ "$month", "$$rev_month" ] },
                    { $eq: [ "$year", "$$rev_year" ] },
                    ]
                }
            }
            },
        ],
        as: "fromB"
    }
},
```

Comment: _"Another problem is that month and year operators are not working in let."_ : You can use the date operators within the `$expr` itself.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-replaceRoot

By default, ROOT = top level  document.

"References the start of the field path being processed in the aggregation pipeline stage. Unless documented otherwise, all stages start with CURRENT the same as ROOT.

CURRENT is modifiable. However, since $ is equivalent to $$CURRENT., rebinding CURRENT changes the meaning of $ accesses."

To change the root that is used for referencing values, you can "replaceRoot".

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/

Perhaps something along these lines can 'namespace' your variables....

```
db.people.aggregate( [
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: {document_a:$$ROOT}} }
] )
```

It's also helpful to remember the syntax/limitations of $join:

```
{
  $lookup:
    {
       from: <collection to join>,
       let: { <var_1>: <expression>, …, <var_n>: <expression> },
       pipeline: [ <pipeline to execute on the joined collection> ],  // Cannot include $out or $merge
       as: <output array field>
    }
}
```